# Pure Java validation framework

Tags: java, validation

Is there a recommendable validation framework that can be used with pure Java code (no annotations)? It should be applicable to domain objects.

Comment: Should we have a [spring] tag on here or something?

Comment: Maybe because of pre-Java5 code (time travel is at our door, if we can go back to 2005 in one question :-))

Comment: @Bozho I'm a bit tired of annotation driven declarative programming and the magic in the background. As long as it works like in the examples, everything is fine ... I like smooth APIs like Google Guice, which I like much better than the annotation driven CDI/Weld.

Comment: @deamon em, what.. Guice relies on annotations as well. It doesn't even have xml config

Comment: ok, annotations can be used with guice, but compared to CDI there are very few annotations.

Answer (score 1):

[Oval](http://oval.sourceforge.net/) has a very good reputation.

And to quote from their site:

> Constraints can be declared with annotations (`@NotNull`, `@MaxLength`), **POJOs** or **XML**.